# NODE API runs on localhost but doesn't run on Vercel

Tags: node.js, vercel

I'm trying to upload a node app to Vercel and use as API but I'm getting an `This Serverless Function has crashed.` error message. The fact that I can run it with no problems in localhost, and the fact that the build log doesn't throw an error, I can't seems to find the problem.

Here is a full Screenshot:
[vercel app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjQre.png)

And here is my index.js:

```
const express = require(`express`); 
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
require("dotenv").config();
const config = require('config');
const dbConfig = config.get("MT.dbConfig.dbName")

mongoose.connect(dbConfig, {
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Database connected.')
}).catch((err)=> console.log('Something went wrong with the database : ' + err))

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/', require('./api/v1/api'))

app.use((err, req, res, next) =>{ 
    res.status(422).send({
        error: err._message
    })
})

const PORT = 5001;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("API is running."))
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hidden",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vercel dev",
    "deploy": "vercel deploy --prod"
  },
  "author": "hidden",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.13",
    "vercel": "^23.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the docs.. I don't think you are supposed to use an express app for a serverless function... but I don't actually know.. I just saw your question and wondered what vercel was.  https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/supported-languages shows a specific function format they want you to use. also, if you look at the logs as it says in the message, it'll probably say that it can't find the function.  What I can't figure out browsing the docs is how you can run a vercel serverless function locally, but I am sure there is a way. Hopefully a vercel expert will come along and clarify